# Design MVC Controller using TDD for database calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd

I am new to MVC and unit testing. I need to do unit testing on my controllers but I'm afraid I may not have them setup properly.

For example:

```
public class MyController
{
     public ActionResult Index(int id)
     {
         var locations = new MyLocations().GetLocations();
         //linq code here that filters based on id
         return View(filteredLocations)
     }
}
```

This is a really simple example, but how would I set this up correctly so that I could use the TDD model so that when I unit test I can provide a static list of locations as the return value?

I am unsure on how this should be properly structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tight coupling because of `new MyLocations()` means you wont be able to manipulate its behavior.

create an abstraction of the dependency

```
public interface ILocations {
    IEnumerable<Location> GetLocations();
}
```

have the implementation derive from the abstraction

```
public class MyLocations : ILocations {
    public IEnumerable<Location> GetLocations() {
        //...db calls here
    }
}
```

and refactor controller to depend on the abstraction

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    private readonly ILocations myLocations;

    public MyController(ILocations myLocations) {
        this.myLocations = myLocations;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int id) {
       var locations = myLocations.GetLocations();
       //linq code here that filters based on id
       return View(filteredLocations);
    }
}
```

The controller is now testable as a substitute can be injected into the controller when testing in isolation, either via a mocking framework or by inheritance.

In production, you would configure the `DependencyResolver` to map the interface to the implementation and inject it into the controller.

Reference [ASP.NET MVC 4 Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection)

Comment: this got me most of the way there.  I ran into the parameterless constructor error and had to add it back in.  I then added a parameterless constructor with a call to myLocations = new Mylocations(); as I was getting a null reference exception.

Comment: @Legionpete that mean you need to configure the `DependencyResolver` to map the interface to the implementation and inject it into the controller.